# Get all documents whose property equals one of the elements in an array

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Post model that has a `publisher` property defined in its schema (I'm using Mongoose). The `publisher` property is a string that refers to a publisher's name.

I also have an array called `sourceNames` that holds all the different publisher names. I want to query my database for ALL the posts whose `publisher` matches any one of the array elements in `sourceName`. My current query looks like this:

```
const query = postModel
      .find({ publisher: { $all: sourceNames } })
      .limit(limit)
      .skip(startIndex);
```

My query isn't returning anything when I exec it. Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible in a single query (Rather than loop over `sourceNames` and make a query for each individual element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short**

Just replace `$all` with `$in`

---

**Expl**

- `$all` is trying to match an **array** with **all** elements in your array.
- `$in` instead, tries to match a **string or array** with one **in** the array.

Comment: Wow. Silly me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @GaviSchneider too many operators. No worries